# Why does this sine-wave generator seem to change pitch?

Tags: audio, floating-point, portaudio

This program is intended continuously to feed a sine wave of 425 Hz
to the default output device.  At first it seems to work correctly,
but after about 12 seconds, the pitch seems to change.  This doesn't happen if the second argument and return value of fillbuf is changed to double; but why does it happen with float; and will it happen with double too, at a later time?

PS.  I should also ask: since this is happening, this is clearly an incorrect way of doing what I'm trying to do; what is the correct way?  Should I simply switch to double, or is there a more reliable solution (if switching to double does in fact just delay the problem)?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>     /* memset */
#include <math.h>
#include <portaudio.h>

/*
* Write a sinusoid to the sound card. --
* 
* Example of basic usage of the BLOCKING technique (as opposed to the
* callback technique).
* 
*/

#define SR 44100        /* sample rate */
#define FREQ 425
#define BUFSIZE 512

FILE *fp = NULL;
float delta = 2 * M_PI * FREQ / SR;

float fillbuf(float *buffer, float initarg);
int play();

int main()
{
    /* for gnuplot */
    /* fp = fopen("/tmp/sine", "w"); */

    play();
}

float fillbuf(float *buf, float arg)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < BUFSIZE; i++) {
        buf[i] = sin(arg);
        /* for gnuplot */
        if (fp)
            fprintf(fp, "%f\t%f\n", arg, buf[i]);
        arg += delta;
    }
    /* print the time */
    printf("%f\n", arg/FREQ/2/M_PI);
    return arg;
}

int play()
{
    PaError err;
    int i, odev, arg = 0;
    PaStreamParameters oparam;
    PaStream *stream;
    float buf[BUFSIZE];

    err = Pa_Initialize();
    if (err != paNoError) {
        printf("%s\n", Pa_GetErrorText(err));
        return 1;
    }

    odev=Pa_GetDefaultOutputDevice();

    /* set all of oparam to zero */
    memset(&oparam, 0, sizeof(PaStreamParameters));

    oparam.device = odev;
    oparam.channelCount = 1;
    oparam.sampleFormat = paFloat32;
    /* takes care of underflow errors and clicks */
    oparam.suggestedLatency = 0.05;

    Pa_OpenStream(&stream, NULL, &oparam, SR, BUFSIZE, paNoFlag,
        /* only for asynchronous mode */
        NULL, NULL);

    err = Pa_StartStream(stream);
    if (err != paNoError) {
        printf("%s\n", Pa_GetErrorText(err));
        return 1;
    }

    while (1) {
        arg = fillbuf(buf, arg);
        err = Pa_WriteStream(stream, buf, BUFSIZE);
        if (err != paNoError)
            printf("%s\n", Pa_GetErrorText(err));
    }

    Pa_StopStream(stream);
    Pa_CloseStream(stream);
    Pa_Terminate();
}
```

Comment: After 12 seconds of 44,100 samples per second, `arg` is around 12•44,100•`delta` = 529,200•`delta`. The format commonly used for `float`, IEEE-754 binary32, has only 24 bits in its significand (the fraction portion of a floating-point representation). That means the rounding error in each addition can be up to `arg`/2^24, which is around 529,200•`delta`/2^24, which is about .0315•`delta`. The average rounding error is around half that, and it means your samples are getting skewed from −3.15% to +3.15% of what they should be. That may be enough to hear.

Comment: Also, a poor implementation of the `sin` routine could explain this. I think that is a little less likely. After 12 seconds at 425 Hz, `arg` will be around 5,100•2π. Some implementations of the `sin` routine might not do well at that point. If you are compiling this as C++ and getting the single-precision `sin` instead of the double-precision, that could contribute.

Comment: From working with Java audio, I've found that using floats for computing the increment is problematic, and now always use doubles for that task. The values that get computed and played can have only 16-bit accuracy, but the point from which the computation occurs probably should be arrived at via a double. Given that, the explanation from Eric seem to me to be spot on. But shouldn't the comment be an "answer"? It doesn't ask clarifying questions of the OP, and actually is an answer. Why is it a comment?